# Undefined reference when compiling a C and C++ file with same header

Tags: c++, c, c++11, makefile, header

To make this short, I have a CPP and C code, and my CPP code is trying to reference functions from the C code with a header file. Whenever I run the make command, I end up getting "undefined reference" errors. Here are my codes:

cpp_code.cpp:

```
extern "C"{
    #include "header_code.h";
}

int main(){
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

c_code.c:

```
#include "header_code.h"

int main(){
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}

void initalize(){
    printf("Initilized");
}
```

header_code.h:

```
extern void initalize();
```

makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11
CC = gcc
DEPS = header_code.h
CFLAGS = -I
OBJS = cpp_code.o c_code.o

c: $(OBJS) 
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $<

%.o : %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
```

Whenever running make it always gives me problems. Can anyone please help me? Thank you for your time reading all of this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Two `main` functions?

Comment: Try to specify the exact error you are getting in future questions.

Comment: Make sure you don't get totally unrelated errors in your example code before you post it. Example: `CFLAGS = -I` will make `$<` be treated as an include directory rather than a source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[basic.start.main](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3)]

> A program that declares a variable `main` at global scope, or that declares a function `main` at global scope attached to a named module, **or that declares the name `main` with C language linkage** (in any namespace) is ill-formed.

So, as a `C++` program, it's ill-formed. Remove the `C` `main` function.

Other problems:

In the makefile you have
`CFLAGS = -I`
and whatever comes after that when compiling will be treated as a directory to search for header files in. In your makefile, that's the source file. Correction:
`CFLAGS =`
or
`CFLAGS = -I.`

Your header file is missing a header guard and header files that are supposed to be used by both C and C++ code usually contain the `extern "C"` part themselves to not burden C++ users to add it.

*cpp_code.cpp*

```
#include "header_code.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    initalize(); // call the C function
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}
```

*c_code.c*

```
#include "header_code.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void initalize(){
    printf("Initilized");
}
```

*header_code.h*

```
#ifndef HEADER_CODE_H_
#define HEADER_CODE_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern void initalize();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

*makefile*

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11
CC = gcc
DEPS = header_code.h
CFLAGS = -I.
OBJS = cpp_code.o c_code.o

c: $(OBJS) 
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $<

%.o : %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
```

Comment: Unless I am misspelling something, which I don't think I am, I am still getting an undefined reference to 'initalize' error. I do want to thank you for being so thorough with your answer though, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @AugustoCelis If you just copy the files from my answer (and make sure the `makefile` get <tab> characters where it should), you will not get any undefined references. You misspelled "_initialize_" but I let that be and it's spelled "_initalize_" in all 3 files - so, no undefined reference.

Comment: It did work. I am sorry for such a late response, but thank you very much!